# asp.net mvc5 custom authorization on HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

If the HttpGet action method has an authorization filter, does the corresponding HttpPost need one as well? The HttpPost action method is protected with a ValidateAntiForgeryToken and data bind. Any user must be authenticated via ldap.

```
[HttpGet]
[CustomAuthorization("Admin", "User")]
public ViewResult MyMethod(){}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MyMethod([Bind(Include = "Vars")] Model model){}
```

Comment: What's the question - whether it's necessary to apply the auth filter for post actions as well? Yes.

Comment: Yes, does the HttpPost need that auth filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filter attribute that you have works on a method. It does not have any affect on other methods. You can put an attribute on the class as well, then it will affect all of the methods (at least ordinary `Authorize` attribute works this way, so I am almost certain it's the case for this one as well).

`ValidateAntiForgeryToken` does nothing with authentication. It just verifies that a token from HTML is equal to the token from the cookie. You can read more about it, but basically it is to protect against CSRF attack, not to authenticate users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if users need to be authorized to make post requests to MyMethod in this case, it needs to have the authorization filter as well.

When you for example go to the URL /{controller}/MyMethod/ MVC routes to your MyMethod action declared with the HttpGet attribute by default, and applies any auth filters and so forth. The same goes for a POST request, in which case the call is routed to the other action delared with HttpPost and runs any filters.